# Firefox is opened but no URL is typed on address bar during executing Selenium WebDriver test

Tags: java, eclipse, firefox, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using Selenium WebDriver for Automated test.
IDE: eclipse
Test Framework: TestNG
Language: Java

```
WebDriver driver = = new FirefoxDriver();
```

After running the test, the following error was found:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  /tmp/testng-eclipse-2118619437/testng-customsuite.xml

org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: FF version? Selenium version? Did you try in other browsers?

Comment: FF version: 5.0.1 I am using WebDriver

Comment: which version of selenium jar?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a proxy to connect to the internet? If yes then you'll need to set a proxy for your FF driver.

First you'll need to import the Proxy class-

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy;
```

Then, you'll need to create an instance of the Proxy class and set a proxy on it-

```
proxy= new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("10.1.2.47:80");
```

Now, create an instance of the FF driver and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It might be a case. In my case, it was version incompatibility of Selenium 2 and FF. I have updated both and working well.

Comment: Which versions of FF and Webdriver do you use now? Now I am experiencing the same problem :P
I am using FF-11 with Webdriver 2.24.1

Comment: you should use FF 12 and above I think. If FF 12 does not work you can use higher version with 2.24.1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved at my end . I tool selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar an all the errors are gone , I am able to run my test suites now .